# Ajuda em portugol

Tags: portugol

Solicitar a digitação de um salário  e o valor pretendido de prestação a ser pago mensalmente. Se a prestação pretendida for maior que 20% do salário, mostrar “Emprestimo nao pode ser concedido”. Senão mostrar “Emprestimo pode ser concedido”.

Fiz em portugol, porem nao fico certo , poderia me ajudar?

```
Var
  salario:real
  pretencao:inteiro
  media:real    

Inicio

  escreval("Entre com o salario")
  leia(salario)
  escreval("Pretençao de parcela")
  leia(pretencao)

  salario<-salario/pretencao

  media<-0.02*salario

  se media >salario entao
    escreval("saldo liberado")    
  senao    
    escreval("nao liberado")    
  fimse
```

Comment: Cara acredito que posso colocar o que eu quiser em escreval , pois nao e isso que e avaliado e sim a logica de programação, leia e reflita.

Comment: 20% seria `salario*0.2`

Comment: Pq vc faz: `salario<-salario/pretencao`??

Comment: Uma coisa estranha que notei é que, se a média é uma porcentagem do salário, ela nunca vai ser maior que o salário.

Comment: também estou bugado rs..

Comment: Acho que tinha que ser `se pretencao < media entao`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica seria esta:

```
Var
  salario:real
  pretencao:inteiro
  media:real    

Inicio                               // Exemplo de valores

  escreval("Entre com o salario")
  leia(salario)                      // salário: 500,00
  escreval("Pretençao de parcela")
  leia(pretencao)                    // pretenção: 80,00

  media<-0.2*salario                 // 20% do salário = 100,00

  se pretencao <= media entao        // 80,00 é menor ou igual a 100,00
    escreval("saldo liberado")       // <- entra aqui!
  senao    
    escreval("nao liberado")    
  fimse
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela Explicação , valeu mesmo

Comment: De nada amigo. Lembre-se que vc pode escolher uma das respostas (apenas uma) e marcar como certa. Sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Lopes Gabiroba. Sou seu fã ! Rs

Answer (score 1):

Acho que era isso que você tentou fazer:

```
Var
salario:real
pretencao:inteiro
media:real

Inicio

    escreval("Entre com o salario")
    leia(salario)
    escreval("Pretençao de parcela")
    leia(pretencao)

    media <- pretencao / salario

    se media <= 0.2 entao
        escreval("Emprestimo pode ser concedido")
    senao
        escreval("Emprestimo nao pode ser concedido")
    fimse

Fim
```

**Em 'matematicol', precisaríamos:**

- Descobrir quanto do salário (em percentual) representa o valor da parcela pretendida;
- Checar se esse percentual excede o limite permitido.

Então, vamos checar.

**Teste me mesa ('caminho infeliz'):**
*Supondo que o indivíduo granha $ 1200 e quer pagar uma parcela de $ 385*

***Regrinha de 3 para obter o percentual***

```
1200 --> 100
385 --> x


1200 * x = 385 * 100
x = 38500 / 1200
x = 385 / 12 
x = 32,08333333...
```

> *A parcela equivale a ~32,08% do salário*

**Teste me mesa ('caminho feliz'):**
*Supondo que o indivíduo granha $ 1200 e quer pagar uma parcela de $ 160*

```
1200 --> 100
160 --> x


1200 * x = 160 * 100
x = 16000 / 1200
x = 160 / 12 
x = 13,33333333...
```

> *A parcela equivale a ~13,33% do salário*

Comment: Olá muito obrigado pela ajuda, me ajudo muito :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Var
  salario:real
  ValorEmprestivo:inteiro
  QTDparcelas:inteiro
  ValorParcela:real    
  VintePorcentodoSalario:real

Inicio

  escreval("Entre com o salario")
  leia(salario)
  escreval("Valor do Emprestimo")
  leia(ValorEmprestivo)
  escreval("Quantidades de parcela")
  leia(QTDparcelas)

  ValorParcela<-ValorEmprestivo/QTDparcelas

  VintePorcentodoSalario<-salario*0.2

  se ValorParcela < VintePorcentodoSalario entao
    escreval("saldo liberado")    
  senao    
    escreval("nao liberado")    
  fimse
```

Fiz bem didatico, da pra melhorar muito essa logico, espero que seja isso que esta querendo fazer

Comment: Cleiton, muito muito obrigado pela ajuda me ajudo muito ! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Var

 salario, valorparcela, vinteporcento: real

inicio

  escreva("Informe seu salário: ")

  leia(salario)

  escreva("Informe o valor da parcela que deseja pagar: ")

  leia(valorparcela)

  vinteporcento <- 20 * salario / 100

  se valorparcela <= vinteporcento  entao

    escreva("Seu empréstimo foi liberado") 

       senao

          escreva("Seu empréstimo não foi liberado")
fimse 

fimalgoritmo
```